# Vim: function to create comment and new subroutine using <cword>

Tags: vim

I'm trying to write a function in my vimrc that would allow me to "hover" the in vim cursor (not the mouse cursor) over the word in question and and create a doc comment (with the word already in the comment) along with the new subroutine.  So I would start with just:

```
newSubName
```

and then hover over and call the sub, it would replace that with:

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Subroutine: newSubName
# Function  : 
# Parms     : 
# Returns   : 
# Assumes   : 
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

sub newSubName() {

}
```

I have the code for creating the sub "declaration" at the bottom of the file (got from internet), but I can't really decipher how to turn it into what I want.  The code that I am using is:

```
function! Newsub()
    let word = "sub " . expand("<cword>") . "()" . " {" . "}"
    let ln = search("__.*__", 'nW')
    if ln == 0
        call append('$', word)
    else
        call append(ln-1, word)
    endif
endfunction
```

Any and all help is appreciated.

Thanks,
RzITex

Comment: Care to explain why you want this behaviour linked to 'mouse hover'?

Comment: @sehe: by hover, I mean that rectangle in vim that shows where you are.  I'm not sure, but I guess you would call it a cursor (not the arrow that is moved by mouse)
Also, by call, I pretty much mean <leader>ns (or some other nmap)

Comment: Aha... Then it should be pretty straightforward. Will try my hand at it tonight

Comment: Yea, sorry about that.  I will know next time to explicitly say that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any templates/snippets expander should simplify your life. For instance, with [mu-template v2.4.0](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/wiki/muTemplate) (only available through svn/vim-addon-manager for the moment):

```
VimL: " {rtp}/after/template/{filetype}/func.template
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Subroutine: <+g:func+>
# Function  : <++>
# Parms     : <++>
# Returns   : <++>
# Assumes   : <++>
# Date      : <+strftime('%c')+>
# Author    : <+g:myname_that_I_need_to_define_in_my_vimrc+>
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

sub <+g:func+>() {
<++>
}<++>
```

and the ftplugin {rtp}/ftplugin/{filetype}.vim

```
" here the anti-inclusion guards, ...
" and the untested mapping
nnoremap <buffer> <c-x>f :let g:func=expand('<cword>')<cr>"_diw:exe "Mutemplate ".&ft."/func"<cr>:unlet g:func<cr>
```

Note: this mapping contain everything that you need:

- obtain the current word (there are many other methods)
- delete that word with `"_diw` (`:h "_`, `:h diw`)
- apply something that will do the expansion. If you prefer to work manually with a function that calls `:put`, name it `s:FuncExpand(name)` for instance, and call it from the mapping with `diw:call <sid>FuncExpand(@")<cr>` (here I use another way to cut the function name under the cursor).

Comment: Thanks.  I will take a look at using this (and templates/snippets expanders) on my own machine.  However, I need it for work where I can't really get vim-addons or use it, and I really don't feel like bending the line (I'm already on my security's list)
also, thank you for explaining it.

Comment: With version 2.3.0 it is also possible, but the syntax will be a little bit awkward to use: viml-expression must be surrounded by reversed exclamation points. v2.3.0 is available through vimball, and it requires the installation of 2 other vimballs as well.